# What are animated logos/text on android usually created with?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio

Developing my first app on Android and I've noticed a lot of logos and great text animations on Android applications and was just wondering how these are usually made? Are they gifs, flash, *.swf, timers(seems like this would be very limited) or animated through Android(Not sure how powerful XML animations are).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML animations can be very powerful and still easy to read and modify. You can animate almost everything you desire: opacity, size, color, coordinates, rotation, apply animations simultaneously or separately, starting from now or after any delay--any way you can imagine.

After you get skilled, you will be able to create custom animated views without using XML nor animation nor interpolator objects--just by you view's `onDraw()` method.

Frame animations are also available--such in which you change images (drawables) quickly one by one.

Android documentation how to create and create and use `Animation` and `Interpolator` objects and apply them to views will take some time to read and learn--but it is really worth it!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually they are created by the images which are changed frequently to give an animation effect. See [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html).

But you can use GIF images also.